# Is it possible to connect two corda networks?

Tags: corda

We have created two corda networks in production mode with Notary and PartyA in one network and PartyB and PartyC in the other one. How can we connect these two corda networks? (FYI - Both networks have separate network root CA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that isn't supported. There's no designed mechanism for merging two zones together at the moment.